# UIsearch Bar Display use in Table view

Tags: ios

Hello guys i am new in iOS .i am try to solve the error in belove code.
every thing is working fine but when i am try to search then we get cell nil. i am use customize cell. i got data in filterDict bt cell is nil show. plz help me

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[TableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
    }

    NSDictionary *dic;
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {

    key = [searchBarSectionFilterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    arrayDictonry = [dict valueForKey:key];
    NSDictionary *filterDict = [arrayDictonry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([[filterDict valueForKey:@"digiboxStatus"]isEqualToString:@"DEAD"])
    {
        [cell.cellImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:105.0/255.0 blue:84.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.cellImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0  green:166.0/255.0 blue:90.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }

        [cell.locationNameLable setText:[filterDict valueForKey:@"locTitle"]];

    if([[filterDict objectForKey:@"lastseenStr"] isEqual:[NSNull null]] || [[filterDict objectForKey:@"lastseenStr"] isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        TableCell *lable;

        [lable.lastSeenTimeLable setHidden:YES];

        [cell.lastSeenTimeLable  setText: @"Not Available"];
    }
    else
    {

        [cell.lastSeenTimeLable setText:[filterDict valueForKey:@"lastseenStr"]];

    }

}
else
{

    key = [dictArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    arrayDictonry =  [dict valueForKey:key];
    dic = [arrayDictonry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([[dic valueForKey:@"digiboxStatus"]isEqualToString:@"DEAD"])
    {
        [cell.cellImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:105.0/255.0 blue:84.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.cellImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0  green:166.0/255.0 blue:90.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];    }


    [cell.locationNameLable setText:[dic valueForKey:@"locTitle"]];

    if([[dic objectForKey:@"lastseenStr"] isEqual:[NSNull null]] || [[dic objectForKey:@"lastseenStr"] isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        TableCell *lable;

        [lable.lastSeenTimeLable setHidden:YES];

        [cell.lastSeenTimeLable  setText: @"Not Available"];
    }
    else
    {

        [cell.lastSeenTimeLable setText:[dic valueForKey:@"lastseenStr"]];

    }
}
return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

    // do your thing

    return cell;
}
```